# Book about a school for teens with powers

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much from it but I remember it was about a hidden school for teens with superpower but there was only like 10 students. The main characters power was a sort of time travel and he described the power as a bunch of lines of yarn and when he pulled on one he would be sent there. The plot focused around his love interest and how he brought her to a certain time and she stayed there since her power was invisibility so his main goal is to find when she is and get her back. The story focused a lot on the characters relationships and less about their powers. Sorry if this is not enough info but thats all I could remember

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a standalone novel or part of a series?  Do you remember anything about what the cover looked like?

Comment: I read this a few years back maybe 3-4 years ago. I'm pretty sure it was a standalone, and I think the cover cover was a hand surrounded by threads of yarn I could be wrong about that though.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be [Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9460487-miss-peregrine-s-home-for-peculiar-children). To take each of OP's points in turn:

> it was about a hidden school for teens with superpower

It is indeed hidden - in a loop of time, situating it permanently in 1940 in Wales. The children with superpowers are called "peculiars", and I think that only the peculiars and certain supernatural beings can cross into and out of the loop.

See [this wiki article](https://thepeculiarchildren.fandom.com/wiki/Miss_Peregrine%27s_Home_For_Peculiar_Children) for more information.

However, I don't think the children were all teenagers. The [wiki page for Olive](https://thepeculiarchildren.fandom.com/wiki/Olive_Abroholos_Elephanta) indicates that she has a physical age of seven but a chronological age of over 75 due to the effects of the loop.

> but there was only like 10 students.

[The TVTropes "characters" page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/MissPeregrinesHomeForPeculiarChildren) lists precisely 10 names in the "Miss Peregrine's Wards" section.

> The main characters power was a sort of time travel and he described the power as a bunch of lines of yarn and when he pulled on one he would be sent there.

This one's not an exact match. [The main character](https://thepeculiarchildren.fandom.com/wiki/Jacob_Portman) was indeed male - his name was Jacob. He was able to enter the time loop and travel back to the house in 1940, but he had no more or less time-related power than the other Peculiars. He did engage in quite a bit of time travel, and time-related shenanigans, but his primary superpower involved seeing and controlling some sort of (presumably invisible) creature.

I can't find any quotes from the book matching the "lines of yarn". Perhaps you're misremembering the loop as a loop of thread? However, I haven't read the book myself - I'm relying solely on online sources - so there may be such a quote.

> The plot focused around his love interest and how he brought her to a certain time and she stayed there since her power was invisibility so his main goal is to find when she is and get her back.

This is an (imprecise) match.

Jacob *did* have a female love interest - her name was [Emma](https://thepeculiarchildren.fandom.com/wiki/Emma_Bloom).

And he did take her out of the loop and into the present day, along with two other children.

However, it was another character, [Millard](https://thepeculiarchildren.fandom.com/wiki/Millard_Nullings), who had invisibility powers. Emma's power was pyrokinesis.

Jacob didn't deliberately take Millard into the present day, but Millard did follow him at one point. If I understand correctly, the time loop didn't loop properly because of Jacob's actions, so he was also indirectly responsible for Millard reaching a later date in 1940 than usual.

OP, if this isn't the correct answer, have a look at the TVTropes pages for [Academy of Adventure](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AcademyOfAdventure), [Superhero School](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuperheroSchool) and [Wizarding School](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WizardingSchool). You might find what you're looking for there!